# Size and alignment of x64 stack arguments

Tags: c, stack, 64-bit, memory-alignment

As I understand the x64 calling convention in Windows (based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention)):

- The first 4 arguments are passed in registers, although 32 bytes of shadow size is reserved in the stack.
- The overall stack must be 16-byte aligned (although individual arguments don't have to be).
- Arguments that are 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes can go on the stack.  All other arguments must be passed by reference.

How are individual arguments aligned? Since I couldn't find anything that specifically addressed this, and based on how I thought alignment worked in x86, I assumed that 32-bit ints could be aligned at 4-byte boundaries.  So, for example, if function arguments 5 and 6 were both 32-bit ints, I would have expected them to be at stack offsets 32 and 36.  However, from looking at my compiler's assembly output, they're at offsets 32 and 40 (i.e., they're 8-byte aligned, even though they take up 4 bytes).

In other words, why does the following function call work in x64, even though it's passing 64-bit `uint64_t`s when 32-bit ints are expected?

```
int i = 1;
uint64_t p = 6;
double v = 2.5;
printf("%i %.*f\n%i %.*f\n", i, p, v, i, p, v);
```

Comment: The should be an ABI or PCS specifying this.

Comment: Already covered well in many places, [like this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/14/58579.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks. I've read that page and others, but I can't find anything that explicitly states whether 1/2/4-byte values are always 8-byte aligned on the stack. What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: @HansPassant - Chen's description seems to take it for granted that they are, but I'm trying to find confirmation that this is the case and/or an explanation of why it's taken for granted, since I seem to be missing that.

Comment: "Parameters that are smaller than 64 bits are not zero-extended; the upper bits are garbage".  That means they are 64 bits.

Comment: @HansPassant - That's what I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: Is `x64` a standard term or an unintentional contraction of `x86_64`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yes, x86-64. ("x64" seems standard enough - MSDN uses it, Wikipedia lists it as an alternative to x86-64.)